# Write a JavaScript function to find longest substring in a given a string without repeating characters

Tags: javascript

"Write a JavaScript function to find longest substring in a given a string without repeating characters."

Here's what I tried, but it doesn't print anything

```
function sort(names) {
  let string = "";
  let namestring = names.split("");

  for(let i = 0; i < namestring.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
      if(string[j] != namestring[i]) {
        string = string + namestring[i];
      } 
    }
  }

  return string;
}

console.log(sort("google.com"));
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `string.length` is 0 on the first loop.  Use console.log inside your loops to inspect the values you're using to control the loop.

Comment: So how should I fix this?

Comment: For one, assign the first letter of names to string before your first loop.  `let namestring = names.split("");  let string = namestring[0];`  -- but also, check that namestring has an index at 0 before making that assignment.

Comment: I think part of the exercise is to figure that out on your own, partly so that you'll understand the mechanics of JS, and partly so that you gain experience and confidence when working on complex problems for which you don't immediately know the answer.

Comment: @JDB I've tried to fix it for like 30 minutes and I just gave up. I thought that it happens because string.length = 0 on the first loop as the other comment said, but unfortunately I didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: @devlincarnate it works now, but it displays googgllllleeeeeeeeee....................ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm for google.com

Comment: I understand the frustration you feel, but if you think the professional devs can solve complex problems in under 30 minutes, then you'll be disappointed when you get your first job. I've worked on problems for weeks before finding a solution. Don't cheat yourself out of a good education... this isn't so much about learning JS as much as it is learning how to learn. The struggle is good for you... don't run from it or give up so easily.

Comment: @f0rta - so, one problem with your code has been resolved.  Now work on the next problem.  Like I said, use console.log() (or a JS debugger) to help you see what your code is doing, line by line.

Comment: @JDB I thought I might get the fix fast so I get to know what I've been doing wrong so I can begin to work on another exercise instead of trying to figure out on my own. But you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function sort(names)
{
    string="";
    ss="";
    namestring=names.split("");

    for(j=0;j<namestring.length;j++) {
        for(i=j;i<namestring.length;i++) {
            if(string.includes(namestring[i]))
                break;
            else
                string+=namestring[i];
         }
         if(ss.length<string.length)
             ss=string;
         string="";
    }
    return ss;
}
console.log(sort("google.com"));
```

It's o(n^2) complexity but try this(may be o(n^3) if contains function take o(n) complexity)

```
function sort(names)
{
    string="";
    ss="";
    namestring=names.split("");

    for(j=0;j<namestring.length;j++) {
        for(i=j;i<namestring.length;i++) {
            if(string.includes(namestring[i])) // if contains not work then  
                break;                         //use includes like in snippet
            else
                string+=namestring[i];
         }
         if(ss.length<string.length)
             ss=string;
         string="";
    }
    return ss;
}
console.log(sort("google.com"));
```

Comment: I'll check this asap. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: "string.contains is not a function"

Comment: can you explain the idea behind this? if(ss.length<string.length)
             ss=string;
         string="";

Comment: let's say in "google.com", when you first start from 'g' you get substring "go", and store it in ss, now when you start from 4 character('g') you will get string "gle.com" which is bigger then "go" , so we store it in ss, and for next computation (for starting with next character) ,we do string=""; so it will pick new string from next character and collect the substring, and after that agian we check it with 'ss' and see if 'ss' is less then 'string', then assign that value to ss.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the answer to be here? Should it be "ogle.com" or "gle.com"? If the first, the below should get you there, if the latter, update the tested = name.charAt(i) in the else to tested = "".

So a few things to note, though you're more than welcome to do as you wish:

1) the function name. This isn't doing a "sort" as far as I can tell, so if this is for your use (or any reuse. Basically, anything more than a one off homework assignment), you may want to rename it to something you'd actually remember (even the example I give is probably not completely best as "pick longest substring" is non-descriptive criteria).

2) variable naming. string and namestring may mean something to you here, but considering we're trying to find the longest substring (with the no double characters) in a string, I felt it was better to have the one we're checking against (tested) and the one we're storing to return later (longest). It helps make sense as you're reading through the code as you know when you are done with a checked string (tested), you want to compare if it is greater than the current longest substring (longest) and if it is bigger, you want it to be the new longest. This will save you a ton of headache to name variables to things that'll help when designing your function as you can get it as close to requirements written down as possible without trying to do some form of substitution or worse, forgetting which variable holds what.

I don't know what you want the result to be in the event that tested length is the same as longest length. Currently I have it set to retain, if you want the most recent, update the check to >=.

Beyond that, I just iterate over the string, setting to the currently tested string. Once double characters are met, I then see if what I just generated (tested) is larger than the current longest and if it is, it is now the longest. Once I finish looping across the string, I have to do the current vs longest check/set again as otherwise, it'd make the final tested meaningless (it went outside the loop before another double character situation was hit).

```js
function pickLongestSubstring(name) {
       let tested = "";
       let longest = "";
  
       for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
         if (tested.length == 0 || tested.charAt(tested.length - 1) != name.charAt(i)) {
           tested += name.charAt(i);
         }
         else {
           if (tested.length > longest.length) {
             longest = tested;
             tested = "";
           }
         }
       }

       if (tested.length > longest.length) {
         longest = tested;
       }

       return longest;
    }
    console.log(pickLongestSubstring("google.com"))
    console.log(pickLongestSubstring("example.com"))
```

Comment: It should've displayed "gle.com". I'll try to understand and see how you've been doing this. Even if I change it like you said, it still displays ogle.com

Comment: By the way, it's just an exercise, that's why it had that name and those variable names.

Comment: It does work only with google.com. If I replace it with example.com it doesn't.

Comment: gotcha. And I misspoke, it wasn't remove the tested setting to current character, have to replace with quotes to clear (updated). And that's interesting for an exercise to do that. You're not sorting, you're just grabbing the largest one (if you were grabbing the chunks and ordering by size, I could see that being a sort). And the variables they use aren't really helpful as they're pretty vague.

Comment: example.com doesn't have a repeating character, so it looks like it works fine for me.

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-function-exercise-26.php I think you didn't get what you have to do. There's nothing about the first string having repeating characters

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive loop that should get the longest string. Uses sort to determine longest string. Works, even if multiple instances of same repeat char.

```js
function longestWithoutRepeat(testString, returnString){
  var returnString = returnString || "";
  for(var i = 0; i < testString.length; i++) {
    if(i > 0){
      if(testString[i] == testString[i-1]) {
        var testStringArray = testString.split(testString[i] + testString[i-1]);
        
        testStringArray.sort(function(firstString, nextString){ return nextString.length - firstString.length})
        
        returnString = testStringArray[0];
        longestWithoutRepeat(testStringArray[0], returnString);
      }
    } else {
      returnString = testString
    }
  }
  return returnString;
}

console.log(longestWithoutRepeat("oolong"));
console.log(longestWithoutRepeat("google.com"));
console.log(longestWithoutRepeat("diddlyougotoofarout"));
```

Comment: This method deals with multiple instances of double characters.

Comment: For giggles... [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/find-longest-substring-after-repeat-string/1) performance test of accepted answer and this answer. Anyone who wants to add tests, please do (these are fun to look at). I have an incredibly long pile of words and test each one... Good times.

Comment: I will try this method too. It seems to be way faster according to jsPerf.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = "pwwkew"

function findLongStr(testString){
    let maxString = []
    let finalString = ""
    testString.split('').forEach((str,index) => {
        if((str != testString[index + 1]) && !maxString.includes(str)){
            maxString.push(str)
        }else{
            maxString = []
        }
        if(finalString.length < maxString.length){
                finalString = maxString
        }
    })
    return finalString.join('')
}

console.log(findLongStr(string))
```

Comment: Please explain the code.

Comment: Here we are taking the string and we are spliting into to the array and iterating each letter, so here when the previous and index value or next index values are same we did not do anything in that case we can get the longest string